# Parse specific array from WebResponse request into an array

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have an external API that returns responses like :

```
{
  "meta": {
    "year": "...",
    "month": "...",
    "reasons": "...",
    "api_data": "..."
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "David",
      "age": 43
    },
    {
      "name": "Jason",
      "age": 23
    },

    {
      "name": "Nissan",
      "age": 32
    },

    ...

}
```

I want to parse only the results array , no need for the `meta` proprety.

I've created an Employee class :

```
public class Employee
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And the request to the API :

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(String reaction)
{
        String apiUrl = "............";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                List<Employee> myObjectList = null;
                var results = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (results != null)
                {
                    dynamic data = JObject.Parse(results);

                    // manipulate data
                    // The following doesn't work since I've already parsed the data

                    // myObjectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(data.results);

                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myObjectList);
                }
            }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "");
}
```

How can I grab all the `results` array straight into a list of Employee ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did everything right. just use `data["results"]` instead of `data.results`

Here is the sample for your information. Using `JObject` to read the `results` array and using `DeserializeObject` to convert the JArray to Object

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(jObj["results"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I advice you to :
Create a class like this :

```
class EmployeRequestResult{
      List<Employee> results;
}
```

As you can see, you must call the `List<Employe>` in the same way as query result here is "results"

After when you get a response you can do this :

`var reqResult = new JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeRequestResult>()`
and to acces to employes data you just can do `reqResult.results`